# Why would one allow clients to switch off XSRF protection?

Tags: security, csrf, bamboo

Some time ago I came across the option in one of the software I use at work, to turn off XSRF server-side protection by including a special HTTP header value on the client side. Therefore, I wonder:

- How is this not a security vulnerability?
- Why would you implement a security feature and allow clients to turn it off? Is there a use-case I am missing?

I am doubting my knowledge of XSRF protection at the moment and since we could not reach a consensus at work I decided to post my concerns here.

The product is Bamboo and they publicly report the option in https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/rest-api-calls-fail-due-to-missing-xsrf-token-899447048.html#RESTAPIcallsfailduetoMissingXSRFToken-Workaround. I first mentioned this in an old answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45090321/410939.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand allowing the server to turn it off on a per API basis. However allowing the client to turn it off is a very bad idea... It's as good as not being there. The only reason I can think this is OK is for backwards compatibility. Maybe there is an older version of the client that relies on this way to mitigate CSRF, while newer clients use the new version, and switch off the older version (but one of them must be used).

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the question around: Why would you implement security features and then ask users to turn them on? This is the opt-in model to security you will find everywhere, e.g. literally no one are forcing 2FA even though it is a huge security improvement.

If XSRF is session based and you run multiple tabs with the same application and you are forced to reauthenticate in one of them you will typically get a new XSRF token. Other tabs might then no longer pass the XSRF check with the risk of losing unsaved work. There could possibly be other similar scenarios.

There are sometimes trade offs between security and usability, in this case they make security default and let people who run into problems take an informed risk.

Comment: "Other tabs might then no longer pass the XSRF check" how do they know whether to skip the check or not? btw that's why it's a bad idea to set xsrf tokens via cookies.

Comment: The header tells them if they should skip the check or not. If the XSRF token is related to the session cookie the XSRF check will fail when the session cookie changes. It is pointless to have a XSRF token only in a cookie, but then you have csurf middleware in Node.js which has a token and a cookie that must correspond, an implementation that makes sense in a stateless environment.

Comment: "The header tells them if they should skip the check or not" wait it's a request header that tabs submit, not a response header that they can inspect. That being said, I still have no idea how they'd decide to supply a XSRF token in a request or simply use 'no-check'.

Comment: I also find the analogy with 2FA incorrect: "literally no one are forcing 2FA". The question here is why if you once enable 2FA, you'd be allowed to circumvent it by supplying a predefined value, say, "0000"

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to mitigate XSRF. So, if cookie is not an option (maybe the client doesn't support cookie), you might want to disable this cookie solution.

Some other ways to mitigate XSRF:

1. State Variable (Auth0 uses it) - The client will generate and pass with every request a cryptographically strong random nonce which the server will echo back along with its response allowing the client to validate the nonce. It's explained in [Auth0 doc](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state#csrf-attacks)
2. Always check the referer header and accept requests only when referer is a trusted domain. If referer header is absent or a non-whitelisted domain, simply reject the request. When using SSL/TLS referrer is usually present. Landing pages (that is mostly informational and not containing login form or any secured content may be little relaxed ​and allow requests with missing referer header

Comment: "There are other ways to mitigate XSRF" the question is why would one allow such methods to exist in the first place? "this cookie solution" it's not only cookies per se, works also via (another) header.